# Replicating SQL server management in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, ssms

ps: I'm not sure "replicating" is the correct term for this.

other than the SQL statements/stored procedures defined for the application's use, we have to use `cmd` to execute anything on the database in case only SQL express is installed (without management studio). no?

since that is out of my control (I mean to have management studio or not) I'd like to provide my application's super admin(IT supervisor in my case) with GUI similar to SQL server management studio new query option.

the basic idea would be to have a `textarea` to enter SQL command, a `submit` button and `datagridview` to display results. this part is feasible.

but I'm debating the idea itself, is it worth being implemented in the first place? what are the trends relating to this kind of situations? any best practices?

if we were to expand the basic idea, I have 2 points:
- SQL server management executes multiple queries at once and displays them is the same result window even if they don't match in columns, would that map to multiple `datagridviews`?
- SQL server management have a `messages` tab to display execution related notes, how to get those message in the application in order to be displayed as well?

this example of management studio from [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2012/04/20/sql-server-2012-management-studio-darker-shades-of-blue-theme.aspx) 
[image: query option]

any pointers to resources, possible duplicates or even the correct SE community I should've posted this on (I tend to mix them up :)) are most appreciated.

Thanks

**update**:
I don't mean providing this functionality for all the users of the application.
since I'm both the IT supervisor and the developer, anything related to the application will end up being brought to me. so I have access to the database anyway that's not a security breach.
but instead of having the application in developing cycle I'd have on-spot fix capability.
for example:
if an urgent report was required: I'd query the requested data in the private IT section without delay, then make changes to the application with no time-pressure.

Comment: Hi Katia, I would not provide the functionality you are describing in the method you are describing to your end users. Providing a way to enter raw sql and then execute it against your database, generally never ends well. 

I see that you are using c#, what stops you from implementing a very simple entity framework model and instead simply using a datagridview with that. If you want users to see all the columns as you are describing, this makes your work very simple, because the datagrid will automatically bind to all public properties in the given collection.

Comment: There IS a free version of the Management Studio (it's called Management Studio Express). See here (for example): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx

Comment: @LouisLewis Thanks for your response, Louis. This functionality isn't for end users, but for "one user only". Like myself as IT supervisor of the application. I'm just preparing for worst case scenarios, or you're saying there will be no situation that needs direct interference? Let's say for example an urgent report was required: even though the application provides a dynamic way of producing reports, there might be a need for an expert pair of hands. don't you think?

Comment: @ThomasLielacher thank you, Thomas. I know about Management Studio Express it's the main option, but in case no extra software are allowed I need to have a backup plan :)

Comment: Katia, sorry I did not see in your question that you wanted to possibly create further functionality, I saw only best practices, and being able to show results for select queries. Using EF, Linq and Dynamic Linq, I have been able to over the years, always prevent any raw sql exposure totally. This was simply my advice, sorry it was not what you were looking for. good luck

Comment: @LouisLewis it's ok, I wasn't clear myself. I've updated the question with more hopefully-helpful info :) I'll consider your advice with pleasure, I still have lots to learn about the real-life applications development. thanks again.

Comment: There are plenty of providers out there that enable you to query back end databases without developing application level code. Two that come to mind immediately are SAP BusinessObjects (not free) and SQL Server Reporting Services. The broader question is, if your organization grants you development access, why would they have a problem with Management Studio Express? It seems like a waste of resources for you to develop something that basically exists for free.

Comment: @wahwahwah IKR! "waste of resources" my thoughts exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already considered using SQL Server Management Objects?

It is basically the same library in which SQL Server Management Studio (and the Express Edition) are based. So you wouldn't have to worry on differences about how you run/execute your queries.

Also, you can redistribute the necessary .dlls, without the need of installing the SQL Server Management Studio itself: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

In our company we use a tool that can run SQL Queries like the one you want, getting information from those objects (SMO) with the same SQL Messages outputs and tables (you can use it to create your gridviews) as SQL Management Studio does. But we use it for the purpose to automate customer deploys/patches.

Comment: I took a quick look at SMO and it's exactly what I had in mind but failed to create a search query good enough for Mr.Google! thanks a lot for the help :>

Comment: I am glad to know I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Katia,

You want to run ad-hoc read-only queries against your database and then give the results to your client.

Make sure you have appropriate database permissions

1. Use the SqlCommand object to send in the sql
2. Get the stuff back as a DataReader (reader)
3. Iterate over the column names with reader.GetName(i)) for reader.FieldCount
4. While reader.Read iterate over the column values with reader.GetValue(i) for reader.FieldCount
5. Parse the above into an HTML table
6. Send the HTML table to your client and get them to open it in Excel
7. Make sure and include the query that you used so that you can replicate/refine

And we're done.

PS Let me know if you need more implementation details